# Как определить последнюю строку в цикле while

Tags: php

```
while($variable)
{
  echo 'string array';
}
```

Как последней строке в цикле дописать к примеру last string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
$variable = array('str1','str2','str3');

for($i=0;$i<count($variable)-1;i++){
echo $variable[$i];
}
$i++;
echo 'Last String:'.$variable[$i];//Если фраза идет после строки, вообще мудрить ничего не надо
```

2)

```
$variable = array('str1','str2','str3');
$last = array_pop($variable);

while($str = array_shift($variable))
{
  echo $str;
}

echo 'Last String:'.$last;//Если фраза идет после строки, вообще мудрить ничего не надо
```

Comment: Слева... галочка...

Comment: @ling, ^^ Danke

Answer (score 2):

```
while(!последняя_строка){
    echo $очередная строка;
}
echo 'last string'.$последняя_строка;
```

А вообще все зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 0):

делай какой-нить переменной инкремент ну а потом выведи последнюю строчку.